# Jquery Dialog with nested form having submit issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have a jquery dialog with a nested form like this:

```
<!-- Store Location Dialog -->
        <div id = "changeDialog">
            <form id = "form" method = "post" action = "Default.aspx" \> 
                <input type = "text" id = "changeText" name = "changeLocation" /> 
                <input type = "button" id = "changeStoreDialogSubmit" value = ""  onclick = "dialogSubmitForm()"/> 
            </form>
        </div>
```

There are two instances that could happen when the button is clicked. One instance will require a page load, and the other will not. I have the non-page load instance working correctly, but the other one is not. Here is the `dialogSubmitForm()` method I have:

```
function dialogSubmitForm() {

    if (!placeHolderVisibility) {

        $('#changeStoreDialogSubmit').submit();
    }
    else /
    {
        //Working code
    }
}
```

And here is the dialog:

```
function createDialog() {
    //Creates a new dialog
    $('#changeDialog').dialog({
        resizable: false,
        title: '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home"></span> Enter Info',
    });
}
```

When I test the page I can see the `$('#changeStoreDialogSubmit').submit();` getting hit, but there is never a page load. Why would this happen?

Comment: is the '#changeStoreDialogSubmit' a button or a form?

Comment: I though I added the code for the html in there. let me edit it

Comment: I think that when you call a js function from html, you don't have to put the brackets. try that way

Comment: try putting an alert inside the dialogsubmitform() method, so you can notice if it's truly validating the condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `.submit()` on the `form`, not the button that submits the form:

```
function dialogSubmitForm() {

    if (!placeHolderVisibility) {

        $('#form').submit();
    }
    else 
    {
        //Working code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `submit()` method  can only be invoked on `form` elements. Your form has an ID of `form`, so you need to change this:

```
$('#changeStoreDialogSubmit').submit();
```

To this:

```
$('#form').submit();
```

That being said, I gather that you are using ASP.NET for your application, and you really need to make sure you do NOT have nested `form` tag, because Web Forms by default will throw a `form` tag on your page for you.